# Fullcalendar: how to display one event per line in timeGridWeek. I am using v5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

[image]

I wan that the events display under each other. the time frame height should be expand according to number of events

Answer (score 0):

Your events are next to each other because they both have the same start time, so they must appear at the same time position in the grid. If you put them one underneath another then it wouldn't accurately represent the start time of one of them, because it would appear to start later, according to the time grid labelling. Clearly that would not be a logical way to display them in a grid-based view, and would be very confusing to those reading the calendar.

If you don't care about the grid and the representation of the start times in this way, then don't use the timeGrid view. Instead you could consider using the [list view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view) or the [dayGridWeek](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view) view.

Comment: thank you. but I want the time grid expand  if there more events.

Comment: That also makes no sense visually or logically, though. Look at your grid - both your events start at 3pm and end at 4pm. If you expand the 3pm slot and put the events one underneath another, with equal height, then it would look to the reader like one of them starts at 3pm and finishes at 3.30pm, and the next one starts at 3.30pm and ends at 4pm . Of course this is not true, but you would have arranged the display in such a way that it misleads them into thinking that.

Comment: Here's what that would look like: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoLQdeY (I've engineered the view by using the times of the events, but the end result is the same as your proposal. Even if the grid were to expand vertically when needed, it would simply stretch the scale of minutes on the left-hand side, and would still be misleading. Fundamentally if you want to get your desired result, but also not make your readers think the event starts at a different time than it really does then you need to not use the time grid - it's _intended_ to show events at their start time relative to each other

Comment: With the dayGrid you get this: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxBYaaz, freed of any constraints of showing the events at a certain point relative to each other and to a grid (and so there is no _expectation_ from the reader that the place it's displayed has any direct relation to the time it occurs)